# PowerShell function return multiple variables with return type not change

Tags: powershell

I want to return 2 `hashset<string>` from function and don't want its return type change to string if the `hashset<string>` only has 1 string element in it.

First, to return 1 variable with type not change, we can use a **comma** before the variable to keep to return type:

```
Function Foo1 {
    $set1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
    $set1.Add("set 1") | Out-Null
    return ,$set1
}

$set1 = Foo1
```

Then, to return multiple variables and keep the return type, I can still use a **comma** before the variable:

```
function Foo2 {
    $set1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
    $set2 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"

    $set1.Add("set 1") | Out-Null
    $set2.Add("set 2") | Out-Null
    return ,$set1, $set2
}
```

But the first calling method can get the wrong answer:

```
$set1, $set2 = Foo2
Write-Host $set1.GetType() # System.Object[]
Write-Host $set2.GetType() # System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]
```

And this calling method can get the correct answer:

```
,$set1, $set2 = Foo2
Write-Host $set1.GetType() # System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]
Write-Host $set2.GetType() # System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]
```

**My Question 1:**
What the difference between these 2 calling methods and why they act differently?

**My Question 2:**
Can we use explicit conversion to keep the return type instead of comma?

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$set1, [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$set2 = Foo2
```

Comment: Why do you  not use a `PSCustomObject` with two properties?

Answer (score 0):

[Comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-)

> As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the comma before the member.

In `Foo2` you return an array, where the 0th slot contains an array with on entry (`,$set2`) and the 1st slot contains a hashset (`, $set1`). As the description of the comma operator states (=`As a unary ...`).

In `Foo1` you return an array with exactly one entry (= `$set1`).

You should rethink your understanding of PowerShell return behaviour. PowerShell is pipeline oriented, thats the reason because:

```
  function Foo1 {
      ...
      return $set1
  }
```

returns a `string`. Reason: PowerShell will return every entry of `$set1` to achieve this behaviour:

```
 Foo1 | Where-Object { $_ -like "*set 1*" }
```

Based on that you'll be able to filter every entry contained in the hashset.

I think what you want is the following:

```
function Foo2 {
    $set1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
    $set2 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"

    $set1.Add("set 1") | Out-Null
    $set2.Add("set 2") | Out-Null
    $rv = @()
    $rv += $set1
    $rv += $set2
    # every entry of $rv1 is returned "seperatly"
    $rv
}

# $result[0]  will return hashset1
$result = Foo2
```

Another alternative would be to return two array with exactly one entry from `Foo2`:

```
function Foo2 {
    $set1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
    $set2 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"

    $set1.Add("set 1") | Out-Null
    $set2.Add("set 2") | Out-Null

    , $set1
    , $set2

}
```

You should also read the docu about PowerShells [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-6) keyword, it behaves differently than in other scripting languages.

Hope that helps.